# Program not encrypting properly

Tags: java

I am working on a program that takes user input (an input txt file, the number of spaces to shift, the direction to shift, and the name of the output.txt file they want to create). My program is compiling, when I run it, it creates an output file, however the results are no where near what they should be. For example if I set it up to encrypt with a shift of 3 and direction is right, the word The should change to WKH. Currently, I have not implemented the direction as I cannot seem to figure out how I would do that to shift to the left. Could anyone be so kind as to look at my code and help guide me into the right direction? Thank you so much for your time!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CaeserCipher {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        String originalText="";
        String inputFile;
        String outputFile = "";
        String shiftDirection;
        int shiftValue;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for input file name
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("What is the filename?: ");
       inputFile = in.nextLine();


       //make sure file does not exist
            File file = new File(inputFile);
               if (!file.exists())
               {
                  System.out.println("\nFile " + inputFile + " does not exist. File could not be opened.");

                  System.exit(0);
               }

         //send the filename to be read into String

         originalText = readFile(inputFile);


         //Prompt user for shift value
         System.out.print("\nWhat is the shift value? ");
         shiftValue = keyboard.nextInt();

         //Prompt user for shift direction
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("What direction would you like to shift? Press L for left or R for right: ");

         //validate the input
         while (!sc.hasNext("[LR]")) {
             System.out.println("That's not a valid form of input! Please enter only the letter 'L' or 'R': ");
             sc.next();
             shiftDirection = sc.next(); //stores the validated direction
         }//end while

         shiftDirection = sc.next(); //stores the validated direction

         //Return encrypted string
         String encryptedText = encrypt(originalText , shiftValue);

         //get the outputfile name
         System.out.print("What is the name of the output file you want to create?: ");
         outputFile = in.nextLine();

         //make sure file does not exist
         File file2 = new File(outputFile);
            if (file2.exists())
            {
               System.out.println("\nFile " + outputFile + " already exists. Output not written.");

               System.exit(0);
            }

        try {
            File file3 = new File(outputFile);
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));
            output.write(encryptedText);
            output.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\nOutput written to " + outputFile);        

    } //end main

    //rotate and change chars
    public static String rotate(String userString, int shiftValue) {

        String convertedText = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
        char lowerLetter = userString.charAt(i);

        //Convert to uppercase
        char upperLetter = Character.toUpperCase(lowerLetter);
        int charNumber = upperLetter;

        //Apply shift, remembering to wrap text
        int rotateShift = (charNumber + shiftValue) % 26;
        char shiftLetter = (char) rotateShift;

        //Create new string of shifted chars
        convertedText += shiftLetter;
        }
      return convertedText;
    }

    //encrypt
    public static String encrypt(String userString, int shiftValue) {
        String encryptedString = rotate(userString , shiftValue);
        return encryptedString;
    }

    private static String readFile(String inputFile) throws java.io.IOException {
      File file = new File(inputFile);
      StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
      String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

         try {
             if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine());
             }
             while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                 fileContents.append(lineSeparator + scanner.nextLine());
             }

         return fileContents.toString();
    }


     finally {
        scanner.close();
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the `%26`. You are not considering how [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters work. You need to do this instead:

```
int rotateShift = ((charNumber - 'A' + shiftValue) % 26) + 'A';
```

What you were doing before was wrong because `char` is an ASCII value. This means that `'A' == 65`, therefore to turn the character representation into a number, you should first subtrace `'A'` from your character value. This maps `A->0, B->1, C->2, ...`. Then when you are done with the `Caesar Shift`, you need to add the value of `'A'` back to the integer to turn it back into an ASCII character.

You may also run into another problem with Java's `%` operator. Java's modular operator operates as follows:

```
-4 % 5 == -4
```

Therefore I would write a cryptographic mod function:

```
public int crypto_mod(int num, int mod)
{
    num %= mod;
    if(num < 0) num += mod;
    return num;
}
```

This should produce the characters you are looking for.

Comment: It does! However, instead of displaying the same (i used an input file that had text on four lines, It displayed it as: `aahsgashashadh*ajshsjahsjahs*ajshaajshaj*jashajsha". Why did it put the asterisk between the lines instead of displaying them all on seperate lines? Thank you for your help and break down of what it meant!

Comment: @still2blue Well, the `'*'` character is less than the value of `'A'`, which makes me think that you are not using the crypto_mod(). Try using crypto_mod() instead of your normal mod function and it should work perfectly.